# Why QuerySyntaxException thrown with Entity is not mapped [from Entity] happened in JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I was working on a web project which making use of Spring MVC and JPA, and it was build using MAVEN. Somehow I wasn't sure whether I have the JPA configuration done correctly because I'm getting this error while launching the web

`Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [from User]`

I have the table in MYSQL created in this way:

```
mysql> desc users;

+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| username | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| password | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| enabled  | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have the User entity declare in this way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="enabled")
    private Integer enabled;
```

I have this configure in `datasource.xml`:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.huahsin.ProjectA.*" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" />
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
</bean>
```

And this is how the DAO is going to invoke the persistence object:

```
@Repository
public class UserDao implements IUserDao {

   @PersistenceUnit
   private EntityManagerFactory emf;

   public User findByUsername(String username) {

      List<User> l = (List<User>) emf.createEntityManager().createQuery("from User");
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`packagesToScan` expects a list of package names. `org.huahsin.ProjectA.*` is not a valid package name. Make sure to specify the package (or any super-package) of your entity in this property.